# Use MySQL Replication Driver with Slick/Play

Tags: playframework, slick, play-slick

I'm using Slick and Play together with the play-slick plugin and I'm having trouble figuring out if I can use the `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` with them. I want to use the master/slave features of that driver. When using Slick only, it seems to be as easy as passing in the driver as an argument to the "`forUrl`" method, but play-slick creates its connections differently. I've gone through the source to try and figure out what's happening but I've come up empty. Does anybody know if this can be done?

PS: This is what my configuration currently looks like:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave/production?autoReconnectForPools=true&roundRobinLoadBalance=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=1000&readOnly=true"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
db.default.slickdriver=scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""
```

When I looked through the Slick source its drivers just seemed to define how to structure data and queries and didn't include anything about actually connecting, so I kind of assumed I'd be able to tell play-slick to use that driver for slick and the replication driver for JDBC

**Update:** So it turns out the above configuration actually does seem to use the proper driver, the problem is I need to apply `Connection.readOnly(true)` for each database operation that occurs as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html). I'm not sure how Play manages its connections, is there a way that I can do this?

**Update 2** So I found the [spot in the play framework's source where it gets JDBC connections](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/b0b459607c1a64cc302da5d6e1d5d9cd75acea2b/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/DB.scala#L65) but I'm not sure how to go about adding anything to that process. Would I have to fork the whole framework to accomplish this or is there a more sane way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to extend Slick's `MySQLDriver` and override `createSession` of the contained `val Database` to always call readOnly on a connection. It may be a bit tricky if you are not used to nested traits in Scala and potential init order problems. Feel free to submit a PR to Slick that avoids them for your use case if necessary.

Comment: if you just create your datasource and database manually, what is the issue?  does play-slick actually handle in which context/threadpool the db calls are made?   If I just have a val ds = datasource will this have performance issues?